# CSS custom colored border

Tags: css

I want to create a top-right border of a div like the following [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veGnq.png)

I am pretty new to css. Could anyone give me a pointer to this?

Comment: Have you tried [**`border-top-right-radius`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top-right-radius)?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I have managed to create the radius using border-top-right-radius but not the color.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an absolutely positioned ::after pseudo element ( or an element in your markup ) to create the green area. Setting the upper right border radius and `overflow: hidden;` will finish the job.

```css
body {
  background: #ddd;
}

div {
  background: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.funky-border {
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.funky-border:after {
content:'';
background: green;
width: 20px;
height: 60px;
transform: rotate( 135deg );
position: absolute;
top: -20px;
right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="funky-border"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way with one element:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border-top-right-radius:30px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 49%,green 50%) top right/50px 50px no-repeat,
    gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```